# spring classpath could not find config file under WEB-INF/classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, classpath

I am using Spring Boot and trying to make my application to be able to pick up a config file while running. Here is what I have in the spring file

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />
```

But I got this error when I start the service

```
Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I tried to change it to

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:config.properties" />
```

I got a different error

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'service.name' in string value "${service.name}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'service.name' in string value "${service.name}"
```

Looks like it could find the file but cannot find the string (which is inside config.properties)

I put my config.properties under path WEB-INF/classes/, inside the war file

```
788 Mon Oct 19 09:54:28 PDT 2015 WEB-INF/classes/config.properties
```

Anyone has any idea what went wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add your `config.properties` code to your post, we will know how you are trying to load config.properties, r u using `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WEB-INF/classes is where I would expect to find classpath resources in an old WAR style app not a Spring Boot application. You should be able to fix your issue by placing the config.properties in src/main/resources instead which is the default location in Maven or Gradle(Which are very popular build tools for Spring Boot and I suspect you are using one or the other).

Second- I would suggest not configuring the location of your config yourself and just use the Spring Boot default location which is src/main/resources/application.properties looking for a configuration file in this location is a convention and should work with no further configuration(Other than removing your current property configuration).

Please refer to 23.3
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot by default looks for the `application.properties` from the classpath, Do you have `application.properties` in your classpath? If yes declare a property `spring.config.location=classpath:/config.properties` in your `application.properties`.

If you don't have `application.properties` file by default, pass the location of your config through command line argument while start up the server like below.

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/cofnig.properties
```

For more information of spring config refer [SpringExternalizeConfig](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)